# OpenCv Setup on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ubuntu

Hi I am trying to setup OpenCV Licence Plate Detection System on Ubuntu 16.

I used this for OpenCV installation 
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`

When I am trying to run the script with python I am getting this

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import DetectChars
  File "/home/tushar/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Python-master/DetectChars.py", line 14, in <module>
    kNearest = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ml'
```

The same Script is working fine on windows installation of OpenCV and Python2.

I am using [This Repository](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Python)

Please Help me with this Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to install Anaconda: https://www.continuum.io/downloads
And install opencv3: conda install scikit-image opencv

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I am going to try this i will reach out to you if anything needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have installed OpenCV 2 instead of OpenCV 3 (ml does not exist in OpenCV version 2)

According to http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

installs openCV from Ubuntu repository and may not install the latest openCV.

You can check you OpenCV version with

```
In [1]: import cv2

In [2]: cv2.__version__
```

Comment: Hi  Thanks for your reply OpenCV Version: $Rev: 4557 $

Comment: You should then follow OPTION 2 from the above tutorial because you seem to have a subversion of opencv 2.

Comment: Hi actually i have already tried option 2 but the result is still the same.

Comment: Did you remove correctly the previous installation ?